# C++: Why do I get a ´not declared in this scope´ error when I included the header?

Tags: android, c++

In my code, I use a class `CameraHeapMemory`, which is defined by [this header](http://osxr.org/android/source/frameworks/av/services/camera/libcameraservice/CameraHardwareInterface.h#0491) on line 491 as follows:

```
 class CameraHeapMemory : public RefBase {
    public:
       CameraHeapMemory(int fd, size_t buf_size, uint_t num_buffers = 1) :
                         mBufSize(buf_size),
                         mNumBufs(num_buffers)
```

I included that header in my source code using an include:

```
 #include "CameraHardwareInterface.h"
```

[my code](https://gist.github.com/gekkehenkie11/2e2811e599716df8ba19#file-wrapper-cpp-L342) then uses the line as follows:

```
 sp<CameraHeapMemory> mem(static_cast<CameraHeapMemory *>(data->handle));
```

But when I compile, I get:

```
  error: 'CameraHeapMemory' was not declared in this scope"
```

Can anyone see why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'CameraHeapMemory' seems to be a private class defined within 'CameraHardwareInterface'. It won't be accessible outside 'CameraHardwareInterface'.

Comment: Í replaced the 'private' keyword in the header with 'public', still the same error.

Comment: Use CameraHardwareInterface::CameraHeapMemory then.

Comment: CameraHardwareInterface::CameraHeapMemory solved it, thanks so much !